# IE8 : page not load completely

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, sass

In a responsive projet, i've problem with loading page on IE8. The page does not load completely (only the header). I use CSS3 media queries JS script for consistent returns on the first mobile IE8.

I noticed several things:

If I remove the JS script, the page loads completely, but in this case the media queries no longer functioned.
However, if I Alege my CSS (about 3200 lines), this page fully loads.

I do not understand where the problem could come, I do not quite ais experience in the "debug" IE8 ^ ^

Someone would have a small solution? Here is my CSS (not minifier with SASS) : http://mfj2km9moq.1fichier.com/

Comment: It might also be your html as well. Are you utilising modernizr, shiv or other systems?

Comment: Yes, html5shiv.js and foundation 5 (for grid)

Comment: Can you link us to your page/website? Anything could potentially be going wrong and this will help massively in debugging.

Comment: Try: move shiv above your css3 media queries. Something is actively not loading. Arent we fortunate that IE comes with a superb network profiler like chrome and firefox! Oh wait.. :)

Comment: I tried :) Made F5, nothing has changed :(

Comment: Ok then you are gonna have to do it the horrible way. One at a time go through the page and comment out each file inclusion.

Comment: I board not quite understand what I should do?

Comment: Never mind. Add modernizr to your code and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: After added modernizr, no change :( I think it's problem with CSS, but i don't know where

Comment: I think foundation 5 doesn't support ie8. You'd think the grid should be generic enough to use, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: It's all good! This was a problem with the script css3-mediequeries, I replace respond.js the page load it perfectly! Thank you for your help friends :)

Comment: if your issue resolved, either answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

If using foundation 5 this provides everything you should need for IE 8:

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/241-foundation-5-and-ie8